# Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline execution hangs during refreshing access token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-authentication

After a successful week of learning and playing with Google Data Flow, I cannot start the execution of any pipeline anymore from my local machine, neither DirectRunner nor DataflowRunner - all pipelines are also using BigQuery.

I've followed again the quickstart guide here (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python) and even this doesn't work anymore.

Any job execution just keeps hanging and showing:

```
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
```

Until it times out.

I thought about an authentication problem, but testing it as of https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started, it shows my available buckets.
I didn't change any configuration about service accounts, roles, permissions, etc., and it just started happening.
I didn't exceed any quota limit too.

Comment: Maybe you should go to your GCP console and regenerate your service account, Maybe something was changed outside of your code which is causing the problem

Comment: Debugging the problem was basically impossible. I rebooted my laptop and solved the issue. Still wondering about the reason... Hopefully, it won't happen again.

Comment: But yeah, tried to regenerate the service account and didn't fix it